# NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, opencv

Getting the error bellow in the code

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
line : crop_img = img[70:300, 70:300]
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

thanks a lot

```
        img_dofh = cv2.imread("D.png",0)
        ret, img = cap.read()
        cv2.rectangle(img,(60,60),(300,300),(255,255,2),4) #outer most rectangle
        crop_img = img[70:300, 70:300]
        crop_img_2 = img[70:300, 70:300]

        grey = cv2.cvtColor(crop_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show where your `img` variable comes from. But somehow it is `None` instead of containing image data.

Often this happens when you write a function that is supposed to return a valid object for `img`, but you forget to include a `return` statement in the function, so it automatically returns `None` instead.

Check the code that creates `img`.

**UPDATE**

Responding to your code posting:

It would be helpful if you could provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That might look something like this:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if cap.isOpened():
    ret, img = cap.read()
if img is None:
    print("img was not returned.")
else:
    crop_img = img[70:300, 70:300]       
    print(crop_img)  # should show an array of image data
```

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read), it appears that your camera may not have grabbed any frames by the time you reach this point in your code. The documentation says "If no frames has been grabbed (camera has been disconnected, or there are no more frames in video file), the methods return false and the functions return NULL pointer." I would bet that the `.read()` function is returning a NULL pointer, which gets converted to `None` when it is sent back to Python.

Unfortunately, since no one else has your particular camera setup, other people may have trouble reproducing your problem.

The code above works fine on my MacBook Pro, but I have to give Terminal permission to use the camera the first time I try it. Have you tried restarting your terminal app? Does your program have access to the camera?

Comment: Just Tried it and did not find a solution, Thankss

Comment: `img` is set to `None` sometime before your code runs. Can you show the code that creates `img`?

Comment: just put it on google drive as it is easier to see thanks( https://drive.google.com/open?id=12S49e7YoX_eHWmVULTL21GcjKjgxgiaa ) ( https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PDPUGUkOgXmjK8GwQSPNDxNHw0eJXHgI )